# Finding the field degree

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Suppose I wanted to find the field degree of the following:

$(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}) : \mathbb{Q})$

Now upon observation I am pretty sure the field degree is $2$ however I am unsure how I would prove that. I should probably note that $(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}) = \{a + b\sqrt{3} : a, b \in \mathbb{Q} \}$

Comment: Can you show it is strictly larger than $1$? Can you show it is at most $2$?

Answer (score 1):

You could use Tobias's hint: clearly the degree is more than one since $\;\sqrt3\notin\Bbb Q\;$ , but on the other side it is at most two since $\;x^2-3\;$ is a rational polynomial having $\;\sqrt3\;$ as a root, and we don't care *right not* whether this polynomial is irreducible or not.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: what is the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{3}$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$?

Comment: Would that be $x^2 - 3$?. This is just an educated guess. I am not completely sure I understand the reasoning that this is the minimal polynomial if it is. In other words, how do I get this from what you just said?

Comment: You can show that the degree of the extension $k(x)$ is exactly the degree of the minimal polynomial of $x$ in $k[x]$ (where $k$ denotes a field). The minimal polynomial is a (the) irreducible polynomial with $x$ as solution. $x^2-3$ is the correct minimal polynomial for $\sqrt{3}$ on $\mathbb{Q}$. Can you prove it?